# Calling a method (hashmap/ hashset) from one class on a string in another.

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, hashset

My code is:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        WordGroup wordgroupOne= new WordGroup ("You can discover more about a person in an hour of play than in a year of conversation");
        WordGroup wordgroupTwo= new WordGroup ( "When you play play hard when you work dont play at all");

        String[] quoteOne = wordgroupOne.getWordArray();    
        String[] quoteTwo = wordgroupTwo.getWordArray();

        for (String words : quoteOne){
            System.out.println(words);
        }

        for (String words : quoteTwo){                     
            System.out.println(words);
        }

    }

}
```

WordGroup class:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class WordGroup {
    public String words;

    public WordGroup (String getWords){
        words = getWords.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String[] getWordArray(){
        return words.split(" ");   
    }

    public HashSet<String> getWordSet(){
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        String[] p = getWordArray();
        for (String items : p){
            set.add(items);
        }
        System.out.println(set);
        return set;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getWordCounts() {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String[] q = getWordArray();
        for (String stuff : q) {
            Integer oldVal = map.get(stuff);
            if (oldVal == null){
                oldVal = 0;
            }
            map.put(stuff, oldVal+1);
        }
        System.out.println(map);
        return map;
    }

}
```

What I am trying to do is use the getWordSet() method using the two WordGroups and 
iterate or loop over the HashSet returned and print the words from it.

Call getWordCounts() on the two WordGroups. Use keySet() to retrieve the set of keys. Loop over this set and print out the word and its count for both WordGroups.

Use the getWordSet() method to make complete set of all the words from both WordGroups.
Loop over the new HashSet to print a complete list of all words with the sum counts from each of the hashmaps.

I am struggling with all of these. Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a combined list or set, you will have to merge the lists together and the maps together. I leave that exercise to you.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

    WordGroup wg1 = new WordGroup(
            "You can discover more about a person in an hour of play than in a year of conversation");
    WordGroup wg2 = new WordGroup(
            "When you play play hard when you work dont play at all");

    wg1.processWord();

    // iterate through all the distinct words
    Set<String> dw1 = wg1.getDistinctWords();
    for (String s : dw1)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    // use map entry to iterate through the entry set
    Map<String, Integer> wc1 = wg1.getWordCounts();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : wc1.entrySet())
    {
        if (entry != null)
        {
            // use stringbuilder to build a temp string
            // instead of using +
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(entry.getKey());
            sb.append(": ");
            sb.append(entry.getValue());

            System.out.println(sb);
        }
    }

}

 public class WordGroup
 {
// as a class, made the results of the process private
private String originalWord;
// we declare generic versions of the Collections, instead of the specific
// implementation
private Set<String> distinctWords;
private Map<String, Integer> wordCounts;

public WordGroup(String s)
{
    this.originalWord = s;
    // here we declare and initialize the specific implementation
    this.distinctWords = new HashSet<String>();
    this.wordCounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}

public void processWord()
{
    List<String> toProcess = getWordList();
    if (toProcess != null && !toProcess.isEmpty())
    {
        for (String s : toProcess)
        {
            // the set will automatically figure out if it should be in the
            // set or not.
            this.distinctWords.add(s);
            // call the update or insert method
            upsertString(s);
        }
    }
}

// this splits the string into a list
// you could probably use a utility class from guava or something to do this
// but i have coded a naive version
private List<String> getWordList()
{
    List<String> splitList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // check to see if there is anything there
    if (this.originalWord != null && !this.originalWord.isEmpty())
    {
        String lowered = this.originalWord.toLowerCase();

        String[] splits = lowered.split(" ");
        if (splits != null)
        {
            int iSize = splits.length;
            if (iSize > 0)
            {
                // basically create a string
                for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
                {
                    splitList.add(splits[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return splitList;
}

// helper method to see if we need to add to the count
private void upsertString(String s)
{
    if (s != null && !s.isEmpty())
    {
        if (this.wordCounts != null)
        {
            // default to 1, if its an insert
            Integer newCount = 1;

            // if it already exists we want to update
            if (this.wordCounts.containsKey(s))
            {
                Integer currentCount = this.wordCounts.get(s);
                if (currentCount != null)
                {
                    // update the count by 1
                    newCount += currentCount;
                }
            }

            // insert the new item
            // or overwrite, because it is the same key to the new count
            this.wordCounts.put(s, newCount);
        }
    }
}

public String getOriginalWord()
{
    return this.originalWord;
}

public void setOriginalWord(String originalWord)
{
    this.originalWord = originalWord;
}

public Set<String> getDistinctWords()
{
    return this.distinctWords;
}

public void setDistinctWords(Set<String> distinctWords)
{
    this.distinctWords = distinctWords;
}

public Map<String, Integer> getWordCounts()
{
    return this.wordCounts;
}

public void setWordCounts(Map<String, Integer> wordCounts)
{
    this.wordCounts = wordCounts;
}

}
```